# Using python to scrape push data?

Tags: python, web-scraping, push

I'm trying to scrape the left side of this news site (= SENESTE NYT):
https://www.dr.dk/nyheder/

But it seems the data isn't anywhere to be found? Neither in the html or related api/json etc. Is it some kind of push data?

Using Chrome's Network console I've found this api but it doesn't contain the news items on the left side:
https://www.dr.dk/tjenester/newsapp-content/teasers?reqoffset=0&reqlimit=100

Can anyone help me? How do I scrape "SENESTE NYT"?

Answer (score 0):

I first loaded the page with selenium and then processed with BeautifulSoup.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.dr.dk/nyheder"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
page_source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source, "lxml")
div = soup.find("div", {"class":"timeline-container"})
headlines = div.find_all("h3")

print(headlines)
```

And it seems to find the headlines:

```
[<h3>Puigdemont: Debatterede spørgsmål af interesse for hele Europa</h3>,
 <h3>Afblæser tsunami-varsel for Hawaii</h3>,
 <h3>56.000 flygter fra vulkan i udbrud </h3>,
 <h3>Pence: USA offentliggør snart plan for ambassadeflytning </h3>,
 <h3>Østjysk motorvej genåbnet </h3>]
```

Not sure if this is what you wanted.

-----EDITED----

More efficient way would be to create request with some custom headers (already confirmed this is not working)

```
import requests    
headers = {
        "Accept":"*/*",
        "Host":"www.dr.dk",
        "Referer":"https://www.dr.dk/nyheder",
        "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"

    }

r = requests.get(url="https://www.dr.dk/tjenester/newsapp-content/teasers?reqoffset=0&reqlimit=100", headers=headers)

r.json()
```

Comment: THANK YOU very much, pawelty! It solves the problem as posted. 

However, it is a bit of a slow solution, and I need to visit the page regularly. Do you have any idea where the data comes from? How is it loaded on to the site? I cannot find it in the html or related api/json etc.

Comment: @bib I have edited my answer. See if it's any better.

Comment: Earlier today I've tried this solution myself but the url doesn't contain the headlines that I need. And I cannot find a similar api that does. My main problem is that I don't know where the data comes from?

Comment: Oh I see your point now... Can't find it either - let's wait for another answers. There are also ways to make selenium faster - use headless browser like PhantomJs, not download pictures etc....

Comment: Thank you for trying. And yes you have a good point about PhantomJs etc. I will look into that if no one can find the "original source".